# How to create IAM policy with a condition that restricts a user to a certain Elastic Beanstalk application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I am trying to create an IAM policy that allows some actions on a resource, but only if the access key is used from a specific Elastic Beanstalk application or container.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I tried this, but to no avail:

```
"Sid": "VisualEditor0",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": "s3:*",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*",
"Condition": {
    "ArnEquals": {
        "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:..."
    }
}
```

Restricting by ip instead works, but Elastic Beanstalk environments frequently change the ips of the servers that they create, so this is not a viable option:

```
"Sid": "VisualEditor0",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": "s3:*",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*",
"Condition": {
    "IpAddress": {
        "aws:SourceIp": "..."
    }
}
```

Comment: 'but to not avail" is not specific. What **exactly** is happening? Any errors?

Comment: Yes, the error message says that the IAM user has insufficient permissions.

Comment: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateInvalidation operation: User: arn:aws:iam::<account id>:user/<iam username> is not authorized to perform: cloudfront:CreateInvalidation on resource: arn:aws:cloudfront::<account id>:distribution/<distribution id> because no identity-based policy allows the cloudfront:CreateInvalidation action.

Comment: Could we see the whole permission statement that you're trying to use?

Comment: @user3553031 I just added in the sid, effect, and action, if that makes it any clearer.  I am trying to allow S3 access to an IAM user whose access key is used from instances created by a specific Elastic Beanstalk application.  So the access key is stored in the application's environment variables, and it is used by the instances.  I want to restrict it so that it can only be used from those instances, so that if a hacker somehow gets the access key, they would also need to be able to ssh into the instances to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Elastic Beanstalk, but here are two things that you can try.

1. Are your Elastic Beanstalk Instances in a VPC?  If so, you could create a VPC Endpoint for S3, make all of your S3 calls through the Endpoint, and use the `aws:SourceVpc` condition key:

   ```
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": "s3:*",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*",
         "Condition": {
           "StringEquals": {
             "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-1234abcd"
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Unfortunately, `aws:SourceArn` is only defined for calls made by a Service Principal.  Presumably, your calls to S3 are being made by a Role.  However, Elastic Beanstalk's Service Principal has to make the call to `sts:AssumeRole` to get those Role credentials.  Rather than putting `aws:SourceArn` constrains on your calls to S3, you could consider putting them on the Trust Policy that controls access to your Role:

   ```
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Condition": {
            "ArnLike": {
              "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:..."
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
   ```